# How to check if arguments were passed in C++

Tags: c++, input, g++, arguments, program-entry-point

I've recently started learning C++ and I'm a bit confused about `argv` and `argc`. I am trying to determine if arguments were passed to a program by checking the size of `argc`, but no matter how many arguments (including none) I pass to the program the size of it is always `4`.

Simple example:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << sizeof(argc); //outputs 4 with 0 or any num of arguments
    std::cout << sizeof(argv); //outputs 8 with 0 or any num of arguments
}
```

I found this same question asked before and I apologise for repeating it but the answers on those pages I found were contradictory to what's happening here.

So, why is `argc` always `4` and is there any other way to check if arguments were passed to `main()`?

If it's relevant I'm using g++ to compile.

Comment: You should check the value of argc not sizeof(argc), sizeof is asking for the number of bytes of memory taken up by that integer, which is 4 bytes (32 bits).

Comment: Sometimes it helps to start thinking before asking questions...

Answer (score 7):

`sizeof(argc)` will always be the same value.  `sizeof(variable_name)` gives you the size that variable takes up in memory.  If you want to know how many parameters were passed you need to evaluate what the variable contains.  For instance

```
std::cout << argc - 1;
```

Will have it display how may parameters were passed.  The `- 1` is needed because the first parameter is the name of the program so we don't want count that in the parameter count.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to determine if arguments were passed to a program by checking the size of argc

`argc` *is* the number of arguments. The size of `argc` is the size of `int` object.

> So, why is argc always 4

Because the size of `int` object is always 4 bytes on your system.

> is there any other way to check if arguments were passed to main()?

You can check the *value* rather than the size of `argc`:

```
std::cout << argc;
```

Note that there is (typically) at least one argument to the program: The command that was used to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` gives you, at *compile time*, the size of the enclosed type.

So `sizeof(argc)` is `sizeof(int)`, and `sizeof(argc)` is `sizeof(char**)`. I hope you appreciate this is therefore completely independent of the arguments passed!

Simply rely on what C++ gives you: `argc` is the number of arguments passed, including the program name. And the number of elements in `argv` is the same as `argc`, with an addional one which is set to `nullptr`.